# Resizing Azure Primary SSD OS disk on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, azure

The 29GB of primary disk coming up with Ubuntu 14.04 are not enough for our needs.
Also (from what I understood), the attachable disks are not SSD.

Is there an updated method of resizing the primary disk, rather then the one described in the somewhat outdated guide here?
https://github.com/azure-contrib/WindowsAzureDiskResizer

Comment: There is no ssd on azure . Only last machine use ssd is d series. And its attached disk . http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/22/new-d-series-virtual-machine-sizes/

Comment: I'm indeed using the D series node, however was certain that primary partition is SSD as well. From what I read, the only SSD partition is the temporary drive, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Azure disk management is not smooth and easy.

To resize your sys disk no other solution than delete the vm with retain disk .
Resize with the tool after deleting the disk from "vm" but keep data in the blob.

After resize you have to add a vm with an existing disk .

Remember to save vm name , disk name , acl in firewall etc .

Last resize of an old azure vm i used this blog post : http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/enterprisedev/cloud/azure/expanding-an-existing-azure-vm-system-drive/

There is a new solution with cloud explorer but i never tested (and you have to delete the vm like the first one methods).

And i don't explain how to expand ubuntu lvm because there is already many blog about that :

( http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/features/resize-your-disks-on-the-fly-with-lvm)

Answer (score 0):

The new [Update Disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157205.aspx) Service Management API allows you to resize your VHD. Make sure your VM is stopped before trying this out. Use the ResizedSizeInGB parameter to specify the new size for your VHD.